# Displaying a NuGet package's dependencies

Tags: powershell, nuget

When you show the Manage NuGet Packages dialog box, it will show the available packages with a lot more information than is apparently available than from the powershell.

In particular, is there a way from the powershell which will list the available packages - or just a single specific package - with the packages they are dependent on, ideally with their target version (ranges)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, there is.

```
# shows all available packages
PM> get-package -list

 # get single package info
PM> get-package -list solrnet.nhibernate

# view dependencies
PM> get-package -list solrnet.nhibernate | select dependencies
NHibernate:[2.1.2.4000]|CommonServiceLocator:[1.0]|SolrNet:[0.3.1]
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be dependencies in the list in VS2015

Comment: This doesn't appear to be PowerShell, this looks like Package Manager in Visual Studio

Comment: @MichaelEakins The NuGet package manager window in Visual Studio is implemented as a PowerShell host, ergo it *is* PowerShell. I know this, because I wrote most of it.

Comment: @x0n So you are saying the script will work in PowerShell and VS?  I am asking as the original tag was for Powershell and not VS.

Comment: Get-Package does work in PowerShell -- from the PackageManagement module which is ironically not the NuGet module which provides a command with the same name in the PackageManager console ...

Comment: @MichaelEakins I'm sure it works, but how you would inspect a local nupkg file, which is just created myself with `dotnet pack`? And also right now I'm on macos

Answer (score 6):

For anyone running Nuget v3 or higher (i.e. VS2015), if you run the command `Get-Package`, you will be given this message:

> This Command/Parameter combination has been deprecated and will be removed in the next release. Please consider using the new command that replaces it: 'Find-Package [-Id]'.

The documentation for [`Find-Package`](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console-powershell-reference#find-package-(for-nuget-3.0-beta-client-or-higher)) explains the new command rather well, and you can see there is no longer a `-list` parameter. Unfortunately it seems neither this new nor the old one will give you the dependencies. You can see all the properties returned like this:

```
Find-Package | Get-Member
```

Which will return:

```
   TypeName: NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.PowerShellRemotePackage

Name              MemberType Definition
----              ---------- ----------
Equals            Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode       Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType           Method     type GetType()
ToString          Method     string ToString()
AllVersions       Property   bool AllVersions {get;set;}
AsyncLazyVersions Property   Microsoft.VisualStudio.... snip
Description       Property   string Description {get;set;}
Id                Property   string Id {get;set;}
LicenseUrl        Property   string LicenseUrl {get;set;}
Version           Property   NuGet.SemanticVer.... snip
Versions          Property   System.Collections.... snip
```

Comment: This is correct, but .. how do you find the dependencies now then ?

Comment: @Noctis Like I said in my answer, you can't do it with Powershell now. There's nothing stopping you forking the [cmdlets on GitHub](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/tree/dev/src/NuGet.Clients/PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets/Cmdlets) though, or even better, submitting a pull request

Comment: For [PowerShell PackageManagement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/) `Find-Package | Get-Member` returns a type of `Microsoft.PackageManagement.Packaging.SoftwareIdentity` in v5.1. This includes the `Dependencies` member of type `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: @wolfyuk maybe you remember and can help, but I cannot get this to work (using VS2019 16.5, doing "$PSVersionTable" in package manager console returns among others: "PSVersion 5.1.18362.628  BuildVersion 10.0.18362.628". Any suggestions?

Comment: @ciuly Sorry, not sure I can help with this now

Answer (score 2):

I used:

```
Find-Package <PackageName> -IncludeDependencies
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/find-package?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score -5):

1. Go to https://www.nuget.org/
2. Search for the package you want
3. Scroll down to the section Dependencies

Comment: OP has asked how to achieve this using PowerShell, not a web browser