# Can a package contain a package?

Tags: c#, package, nuget, nuget-package

Installing Packages from Nuget are one of the most efficient ways for developing C# applications. It's a huge time saver.

However, can a Package I install from Nuget also contain a package(s) installed within it? If so how can I view sub-packages within a Package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is yes, you can use packages inside of other packages. They are called dependencies, and the other packages will get installed along side the first package. Here's the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution) on nuget package dependency.

EDIT:
Here's how to view/manage these [in visual studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio). You can view all other packages in the dependencies section shown below. This package depends on System.ValueTuple with a version of 4.5.0 or greater.
[image]

Comment: Is there any way to see the packages installed within a package in Visual Studio?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037745/displaying-a-nuget-packages-dependencies

Comment: I'm not familiar with using the command prompt for accessing or viewing files. Is there any way to view what is in a package in the Visual Studio IDE?

Comment: I updated the answer with that information.

Comment: Just as a confirmation: "Dependencies" will always list the package(s) within a package?

Comment: Yes, it will always list any packages needed to run a given package.